# How to find row of a widget?

Tags: gwt

I have a widget that I've added to a FlexTable. I would like to find its current row.

One solution is to enumerate through all the rows of the table and see if it matches my widget.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this in response to an event then you an use the getCellForEvent method to find the cell (row / column).

Comment: I was trying to catch hover events on the FexTable rows. My solution was to wrap each row in a horizontal panel and catch the hover events on that. Each panel has a remove button. When it is clicked I want to know what row that panel is currently in so that I can remove the table row.